# Failed to install package on Windows; 'Fatal error during installation'

Tags: puppet

While trying to install a package on Windows using puppet, I get the following error.

```
Debug: Prefetching windows resources for package
Debug: Executing: 'msiexec.exe /qn /norestart /i C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\LAPS.x64.msi'
Error: Failed to install:  Fatal error during installation.
Error: /Stage[main]/installlaps/Package[laps]/ensure: change from 'absent' to 'present' failed: Failed to install:  Fatal error during installation.
```

I tried executing the command manually, this worked without any incident.

The code I want to execute:

```
  package { 'laps':
  ensure          => 'present',
  source          => 'C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\LAPS.x64.msi',
  }
```

**EDIT:**

I found that this error does not occur when I use a direct weblink. However, I am now running into idempotency issues.

```
  package { 'laps':
  ensure          => 'present',
  source          => 'https://download.microsoft.com/download/C/7/A/C7AAD914-A8A6-4904-88A1-29E657445D03/LAPS.x64.msi',
  }
```

Comment: You can execute the puppet agent with `--debug` for useful information about the failure, as currently nothing can be gleaned from just a message about a fatal error occurring.

Comment: The above message already has the debug mode enabled. Although I do agree with you that it is not much information. However, this is all it gave me.

Comment: Then if that command executes successfully, the solution might become obscure and esoteric.